# Difference between self.collectionView and UICollectionViewCell.self

Tags: ios, swift

I know that self.collectionView for example refers to the property of the current instance. However, when i encounter this syntax UICollectionViewCell.self in:

```
collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellID")
```

From apple doc:

```
func register(_ cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String).
```

> cellClass: The class of a cell that you want to use in the collection view.

I am confusing what does the syntax actually refers to?

Answer (score 3):

You understand that "self.collectionView" refers to the collection view that you created and present on the screen. You (or interface builder) create that view. "self", in this case is the view controller which contains your collection view.  That's half the story -- the other half is done by the system.

Your collection view gets filled with data, cell by cell.  You need to tell your collection view what kind of cell to use (it can be a custom-designed cell, or a plain old UICollectionViewCell).  The way you do that is to "register" your cell.  This tells the collection view what kind of cell to  create when it needs one.

One last point before I tie it all together:  you can have different kinds of cells in your one collection view.  Maybe some have images, some cells might just be plain text, others could have a combination.  The way this made possible is by requiring you to register your cells with an associated ID, to make it easier for you to select a certain type of cell whenever a cell is needed.

The registration syntax accomplishes two things. For each type of cell you want to use (and very often it is only one), you register the kind of cell you want. That's where the "UICollectionViewCell.self" comes in.  It could be "MyCell.self", etc. The .self here just means use this class as the template to create the cell. The second part of the registration is to attach the identifier to the template/class for easy reference.

self.collectionView  - self is the view controller

UICollectionViewCell.self - self is the "instancetype" of the cell to be used. The system uses this information to construct a cell for you.

Answer (score 1):

TypeName.self will return the type of the TypeName if that TypeName inherits from NSObject class, this is a method in NSObject class as Abhishek suggested

```
- (instancetype)self;
```

If you have made a subclass of say **UICollectionViewCell**

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
}
```

you would use it like this

```
collectionView?.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
```

This will return CustomCell (instanceType or AnyClass)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionViewCell.self refers to the type of Class you want to use for cell.

```
- (instancetype)self;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote

```
collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellID")
```

This referring that you are about to use predefined `collectionviewcell`,

of-course if we define custom cell then we write it as

```
self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCollectionViewCell",bundle : nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCollectionViewCell")
```

when we type `self.`is referring that we are using current class variables

Answer (score 0):

func register(_ cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String).

This method tells the collection view that which Cell Class's objects it is going to reuse. This is how you can understand this method signature.

The register method needs two parameter one is a kind of AnyClass and another is of String. AnyClass means you are going to pass the class whose objects can be reused for collection view cell. You just need to mention the type of object (Class), not any particular object.

For more about types see [Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-XID_1022)